# How to setup failover capability for an AutoSys job?

Tags: autosys

I have two unix servers, x1 and x2.

x1 is the primary server and x2 is the failover server.

In normal scenarios where x1 is up and running, we don't want anything to be run on x2. All the load should be handled by x1.

If x1 goes down, we want x2 to take on the load.

Is this easily achievable in AutoSys? I understand that there's load balancing capability, but we don't want both machines to be handling the load.

Looking at the AutoSys guide, I was thinking of maybe trying this example:

insert_machine: myvirtualmachine
machine: x1
factor: 1
machine: x2
factor: .01

The idea is to set the factor so low for x2 that it should never pick up any of the work unless x1 goes down. But I find this solution a bit crude.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real way of doing this in Autosys. What we did is have a DNS entry created and instead of having the machine definition on the server it self it was setup for the DNS entry. If the 01 goes down the DNS knows to send traffic to 02.

So not handled by Autosys but your Cisco or F5 with DNS created.

Let me know if that helps.
Dave

Comment: This is a great answer! We do have F5 appliances and never thought about this solution. Thank you.